# How to import and use the CryptProtectData method correctly

Tags: c++, winapi

[image]

I want to encrypt some text in my program using that method.
I included the dpapi.h header file, but I was told that the method was not defined.

How do i fix this?

Comment: who say that `CryptProtectData` not defined ?

Comment: RbMm, the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: and so what ? ignore Visual Studio IDE. only compiler decide this

Comment: You need to include `windows.h` before including `dpapi.h`

Comment: @RbMm compiler says the same too, because inclusion of `dpapi.h` fails

Comment: @Arkady In future could you include code as text in a formatted code block rather than an image. That makes it easier for people to reproduce. Also, please translate any messages that aren't in English. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan *because inclusion of dpapi.h fails* - yes (not included <windows.h> before )but exist too many another errors and that `CryptProtectData`  undefined symbol - not first error. if post compiler ouput - this became more clear

Comment: @RbMm yes that's fair, compiler of course objects in dpapi.h compilation first